# Ajaxed div hide and show hides only after div load

Tags: ajax, html, hide, show

I have this issue. I'm working on a jquery ajaxed site. I have the main content div in the middle and on top the navigation. I need to AJAX the content, because I have flash backgound so that the flash video won't start from beginning after every page load. The only way I was able to do this was with this sort of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$.ajaxSetup ({  
         cache: false  
         }); 

//For loading
     var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' /><p>";  

 //  Var
    var loadPage1 = "page1.html";

//  Load page
    $("#page1").click(function(){
            $("#content").hide(2000);
            $("#content").html(ajax_load).load(loadPage1);
            $("#content").show(2000);
});
```

All other ways to get the div didn't work because there was issues on getting plugins etc. working in the ajaxed div (content).

So... everythig is working fine - but, the div loads it's content from page1.html and shows it and only after this does it hide it and show it. So it loads the page and then does the effects I want to.

Do I need to queue this some how or what's the proper jquery way? I tried delay, stop etc.. but can't seem to solve this out. It's propably very simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Show the element in the load callback handler.
i.e:

```
$("#page1").click(function(){             
    $("#content").hide();             
    $("#content").html(ajax_load).load(loadPage1, function(){
        $("#content").show(2000)
    });
});
```

Comment: I like it, but what if the content loads in less than 2 seconds?

Comment: The effect will be applied only after the request is complete. Hence it shd not have any impact.

Comment: Oh wait... my mistake, I thought you added a duration to the hide() method :)

Comment: Years later this has helped me!

Answer (score 0):

.load() takes 2 arguments, the URI and a callback to fire after load.
API is found here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
function() {
    $("#content").hide(2000);
    $("#content").html(ajax_load).load(loadPage1, function() {
        $("#content").show(2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Ofcourse when using .hide() without vallue for speed the content doesn't have time to load in the div. But otherwise still it loads first and then the div does .hide() & .show() effects.