# Hide an element after .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide

I'm creating a login popup, goal is, to login without a page refresh.
After login, I refresh my page `#wrap` with following code:

```
$('body').find('#wrap').load(window.location.href + ' #wrap');
```

I noticed, that my JQuery Code is not working after this. For example .click does not work after my `.load()`, so I'm using

```
$("body").on("click", "#settings-gear", function(event)
```

This works perfect, but now I have another problem:

How can I hide an element from load ? I searched for solutions ...

Before my `.load()` function, i'm hiding with

```
$('#settings').hide();
```

Greets

Comment: Can you maybe provide a small working fiddle ? I think I understand your question in general but it is somewhat not clear.

Comment: I know, how to solve my problem. I dont know, if this is the best way, but it works fine :)
Just hide the element in css with display: none;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajaxed div hide and show hides only after div load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007563/ajaxed-div-hide-and-show-hides-only-after-div-load)

Answer (score 1):

`load()` provides a complete callback that fires after the html has been inserted.

Within the callback `this` is the element represented by the initial selector

```
$('#wrap').load(window.location.href + ' #wrap', function(){
      /* new content exists, can run code for it here */
      $(this).find('.someClass').doSomething();      
});
```

Reference : [load() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)